# How to set iframe padding inside p?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to remove padding from `iframe` but `<p>` must have padding. The problem is `iframe` is a child of `p`. Here is structure of code:

```
<div class="post">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p><iframe></iframe></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post p{
padding: 10px;
}
```

Tried to make `.post > p > iframe{ padding: 0px; }` but it's not working because iframe is a child.

Answer (score 0):

Add `p` inside `iframe` not `iframe` inside of `p`.

If this doesn't work, create a `id` or `class` inside `iframe` and add padding inside that `id`/`Class`.

This will surely solve your issue but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I wll try my best to help you.

Comment: It's actually `iframe` inside of `p`. Wordpress makes this kind of code when I insert a youtube video.

Comment: @AkramBaratov I have made some changes in my answer, try it and if it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: how can I create `id` or `class` inside `iframe` if... the first is Wordpress generates `p > iframe` itself, the second is - `iframe` inside `p`, not `p` inside `iframe` and I can't create some `class` or `id` inside `iframe` beacuse it generates automatically. My task is to remove padding from this p where exists iframe.

Comment: @AkramBaratov I am really sorry I don't have any idea about that but can you do me a favour  that as soon as you resolve this issue please let me know, I would love to know how you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying ***nth-of-type(n)***, where *'n'* is number of class or div location. Try the below it should apply the style to first p only

```
.post p:nth-of-type(1){
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The main problem is I don't know where would be `iframe` in `p`. It could be in first p or in third.